# Airbag light blinking after ignition switch replacement

Tags: troubleshooting, gmc, supplemental-restraint-system, sierra

I am looking for some troubleshooting guidance on a 96 GMC Sierra C1500.

I had to replace the ignition switch and now the airbag light on the dash blinks 7 times and stays on constantly. I checked the fuse in the fuse panel it and it is good.  I don't know where to start.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the codes as to what this error may be? It may also be that the new switch needs to be programmed to the vehicle as part of the installation - did you do that?

Comment: didn't you remove the battery terminal head -(negative) when you are installing the spark plug coil

Comment: @OlaJamiu spark plug ? The OP changed the ignition (key) switch.

Comment: Recheck your work. Check that you didn't disturb the connectors for the Air bag or clock spring.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the ignition has a ground to the computer. Try resetting the computer by disconnecting ground post for about 10 min. If that doesn't work you may need a scanner to reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the airbag and steering wheel when you replaced the ignition switch, it is probably the clockspring.  Typically there is a device called a clockspring used to make the connection between the lower part of the steering column and the stuff that is embedded in the steering wheel, including the airbag, horn switch, etc.  That device can be delicate, and you may have unknowingly damaged it.  You might also have simply left it disconnected.  Does the horn still blow?

Here's a vid showing how they're replaced.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpmSEbQu5A8